# haskell function definition IO

Tags: haskell, io

Give a definition of the function 
fmap :: (a->b) -> IO a -> IO b

the effect of which is to transform an interaction by applying the function to its result. you should define it using the do construct.

how should I define the fmap? I have no idea about it?

could someone help me with that?

Thanks~!

Comment: How familiar are you with Functors and Monads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like homework or something so I will give you enough hint so that you can work rest of the details yourself.

```
fmap1 :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b 
fmap1 f action =
```

`action` is as `IO` action and `f` is a function from `a` to `b` and hence type `a -> b`.

If you are familiar with monadic bind `>>=` which has type (simplified for `IO` monad)

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

Now if you look at

```
action >>= f
```

It means perform the `IO` action which returns an output (say `out` of type `a`) and pass the output to `f` which is of type `a -> IO b` and hence `f out` is of type `IO b`.

If you look at the second function called `return` which has type (again simlified for `IO` monad)

```
return :: a -> IO a
```

It takes a pure value of type `a` and gives an `IO` action of type `IO a`.

Now lets look back to `fmap`.

```
fmap1 f action
```

which performs the `IO` action and then runs `f` on the output of the action and then converts the output to another `IO` action of type `IO b`. Therefore

```
fmap1 f action = action >>= g 
    where
        g out = return (f out)
```

Now comes the syntactic sugar of `do` notation. Which is just to write bind `>>=` in another way.

In `do` notation you can get the output of an action by

```
out <- action
```

So bind just reduces to

```
action >>= f = do 
    out <- action 
    f out
```

I think now you will be able to convert the definition of fmap to do construct.

Comment: thanks so much! and I think the last part of your code should be return (f out), right? not f out

Comment: @Justin Does that matter ? Try running both and see.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with map?

The type of map is

map :: (a -> b) - > [a] -> [b]

if you run

map (*5) [1,2,3]

you get

[5,10,15]

The point of map is to give it a transform function and a source list and have it apply the transform to the list to get a result list.

map is fmap for lists. They want you to write an fmap for IO types, does this help?

if You want to know more about fmap read http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass

Answer (score 1):

Note that every monad is a already a functor. If you want to reimplement `fmap`, however, you can do that in terms of monadic functions easily. One [monad law](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#t%3aMonad) is this:

```
fmap f xs = xs >>= return . f
```

If you understand do notation enough, you should be able to translate that yourself. If not, just ask.